# Django custom user model with django-polymorphic

Tags: python, django

I have some problems with getting correct model names when try to get it via `user = request.user`, it shows every user like User, even if it is Student.
Okay, more details here:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    pass

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    pass

class Student(User):
    pass
```

When in view code I try to get user = request.user, I need to get user model name to show them different views. I tried it with django-polymorphic, it works good for other objects but when I try to inherit from it everything goes down, I do not understand how to do it.
i tried something like this:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PolymorphicModel):
    pass
```

and in manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager, PolymorphicManager):
    pass
```

but it doesnt work, could someone please show me how to configure them together or say better way to get correct model names from request.user

Comment: You need to use a statement to differentiate between them. How are the users unique? I.E. Do they have different user groups? If so, you can do something like: `isStudent = request.user.groups.get(name='Student')`. Then use this in your view in an `if` statement.

Comment: I found some decicion here without django-polymorphic, but I would love to know more about using django polymorphic. [Here it is] (http://djbook.ru/forum/topic/3145/)

Comment: I've never played with polymorphic before and I don't currently have the facilities to test this until later today. Are you still having a problem???

Comment: I posted an answer, but maybe anyone will give better decicion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some decicion, here is code:

```
class InheritanceMetaclass(ModelBase):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(InheritanceMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj.get_object()

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    __metaclass__ = InheritanceMetaclass

    object_class = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    objects = BaseUserManager()


   def get_object(self):
       if not self.object_class or self._meta.model_name == self.object_class:
           return self
       else:
           return getattr(self, self.object_class)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if not self.object_class:
          self.object_class = self._meta.model_name
      super(User, self).save( *args, **kwargs)

# inherits
class User1(User):
    text1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text2 = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class User2(User):
    text3 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text4 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

It seams it works but I am sure should be better way to do it.
now you can get user class name in object_class attribute, `user.object_class`

1 more way here:

```
def get_class_name(instance):
    return instance.__class__.__name__
```

and then:

```
classname = get_class_name(user)
```

But I do not think it is good ways anyways...